# What does 亮黄灯了 mean in 我承认，应该是运动量过大，身体亮黄灯了?

Tags: translation, meaning

Can someone please tell me what 亮黄灯了 means in this sentence:

> 我承认，应该是运动量过大，身体**亮黄灯了**

And why is the colour yellow (黄) used?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This probably refers to the *orange light* (黄灯) in a *set of traffic lights*.

Essentially when the orange light lights up, it's time to slow down and stop. In this case, it refers to your body switching to the "orange light" (muscle cramps, short of breath and etc...), which is a sign for you to slow down and take a break from excessive exercising.

Comment: But 黄 is yellow，orange is 橙。

Comment: Yes... it's normally called 'orange' in English. Some people do say yellow, but I don't hear that often. Don't get caught up on stuff like this. It's like some people call turquoise a shade of blue, while others call it a shade of green. People have different perceptions of what a colour looks like. I can carry on with this psychology topic, but I think I've made myself clear.

Comment: @Krazer as a native Chinese speaker, I confirm that deutschZuid is right :) we call that 黄灯, and the metaphor of 亮黄灯 is just as what is said in this answer.

Comment: @deutschZuid In my experience (US), we say "Yellow light".

Comment: @StumpyJoePete Yellow light is gaining ground here. Still many here still go with the original (I presume?) orange colour. In fact, rarer still, some actually call it amber light. It's good to know however. Thanks.

Comment: @StumpyJoePete Here is an interesting web snippet about how it's used in different countries based on user feedback :). http://365project.org/eleanor/365/2011-02-15

Comment: @deutschZuid It depends on the actual colour -- in some countries the light colour is closer to orange (for instance, Germany) but in others closer to yellow (for instance, USA)

Comment: @user58955 Thanks for the feedback.. but I am fully aware of the differences in the actual RBG composition of the yellow/orange light in different countries. This is really not the point of this post at all.

Answer (score 5):

The color yellow is a sign of warning.
Here in your sentence, it is a metaphor of traffic lights (IMO). green->yellow->red

> 我承认，应该是运动量过大，身体*亮黄灯了*

the quote 亮黄灯了 means that your body (身体) is warning you, e.g. headache, dizziness or some physical discomfort.

Answer (score 1):

That is a metaphor, a yellow alert for your body conditions.  It means your health is going bad, but can be restored by rest and care attention.
If it goes to red alert, then your body is in dangerous situation and mostly is about to collapse.

Answer (score 0):

It's meaning a warn.The yellow light.